# RxAndroid upload multiple files and store success in DB

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I have the following use case:

1. Get a list of entities from the DB
2. Iterate over all entities and get all attached files
3. Iterate over all attached files and upload each    file to the server
4. If all files of the entity are uploaded successfully, update the entity and store it to the DB
5. If all    entities are done return `onComlete()`

I have a list of entities. Each entity has 0..n files attached. I want to upload each file and store it as successful, if all files of the entity are uploaded.

Currently I do it like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(entities)
                .flatMap(entity -> {
                            //create a list of executable observables
                            List<Observable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
                            // get all files of the entity
                            List<File> files = entity.getFiles();

                            // iterate through all files and upload the file. If successful -> store entity
                            files.forEach(file -> tasks.add(uploadImage(file)
                                    .doOnComplete(() -> {
                                        entity.update(entity.setUploaeded(true));
                                        repository.store(entity);
                                    })
                            ));
```

Here ist my `whenAll` methode:

```
private Observable whenAll(List<Observable> tasks) {
return Observable.fromIterable(tasks)
        .flatMap(task -> task.observeOn(Schedulers.computation()));
}
```

**I would like to remove the helper method `whenAll`. Is this possible?** Here is what it should look like:

```
Observable.fromIterable(entities)
            .flatMapIterable(entity -> {
                List<File> files = entity.getFiles();
                return files;
            })
            .flatMap(file -> uploadImage(file))
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                // TODO: update entity and store it
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential solution that you have presented is not entirely possible, because when you map entities to files, you lose information about entity in downstream.

As you have tagged this as RxJava2 I will use Completables. I assume that `uploadImage(file)` method returns Complete (if it doesn't you can easily convert it) . The solution for your problem could look like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(entities)
    .flatMapCompletable(entity-> 
          Observable.fromIterable(entity.getFiles())
              .flatMapCompletable(this::uploadImage)
              .doOnComplete(() ->{                                      
                   entity.update(entity.setUploaeded(true));
                   repository.store(entity);
              }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
```

As a result you will also get a Completable. What I do here is:

1. For every entity
2. For every file in this entity
3. Upload image
4. Wait for all the images to be uploaded and then save the entity to database.
5. Subscribe on different thread so that all entities can be handled in parallel.

I didn't get a chance to test this solution, because I am not able to open AndroidStudio right now. Please let me know if it helps or whether it needs some changes.